# Error installing gtk# on windows 8.1

Tags: unity-game-engine, mono, monodevelop

I updated my unity to 5.5 but the monodevelop came with it do not starts.
I did some research and downloaded the gtk# but when tried to install, it gave me this error [image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: What type of error do you get when trying to start monodevelop?

Comment: @CNuts It gives me error metioned here - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5DLdOoAYZCQ. When i start monodevelop